# Laravel FullCalendar Cant register Same Hour in diferent Day

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar, scheduler

I am doing a reservation system ... and I am having the following problems:
if a customer registers 11/06/2020 - 11:00 to 12:00
it lets me register 11/06/2020 - 1:00 p.m. to 3:00 p.m. for example but not ...
11/07/2020 - 11:00 to 12:00
He says the schedule is already busy, but he's not comparing the day to me ...

```
public function validarFecha($fecha, $horaInicial, $horaFinal)
    {
        $agenda = Booking::select("*")
            ->whereDate('day', $fecha)
            ->whereBetween('hour_start', [$horaInicial, $horaFinal])
            ->orWhereBetween('hour_end', [$horaInicial, $horaFinal])
            ->first();

            return $agenda === null || $agenda->hour_end === $horaInicial
    } 

-----------------------------

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        if($this->validarFecha($input["txtFechaInicio"], $input["txtHoraInicio"], $input["txtHoraFinal"])){
            $agenda = Booking::create([
                "id_user"=>$input["ddlUsuarios"],
                "day"=>$input["txtFechaInicio"],
                "hour_start"=>$input["txtHoraInicio"],
                "hour_end"=>$input["txtHoraFinal"],
                "observation"=>$input["txtDescripcion"]
            ]);

            return response()->json(["ok"=>true]);
        }else{
            return response()->json(["ok"=>false]);
        }

        dd($input);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this was because of `whereBetween`. You should have nested condition under `where` something like this,

```
public function validarFecha($fecha, $horaInicial, $horaFinal)
{
   $agenda = Booking::whereDate('day', $fecha)
                    ->where(function ($q) use ($horaInicial, $horaFinal) {
                       return $q->whereBetween('hour_start', [$horaInicial, $horaFinal])
                                ->orWhereBetween('hour_end', [$horaInicial, $horaFinal]);
                   })
                  ->first();

    return $agenda === null || $agenda->hour_end === $horaInicial
}
```

If stil this not work check with your sql query generated by laravel using this, `->toSql()`.

[Laravel Nested Where](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: I love you, it work!! i will read to Nested... only u miss a ";" 
->orWhereBetween('hour_end', [$horaInicial, $horaFinal])
to... 
->orWhereBetween('hour_end', [$horaInicial, $horaFinal]) ;

Comment: Yeah, I missed `;`. I updated my answer. If you find it helpful please accept it as an answer so it helps to others also :)